# How to Match Salesforce Fields via REGEX in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, salesforce, regex-lookarounds

Consider the following multi-line string:

```
CreatedDate
Account.Example_1__c
Account.LastModifiedDate
Test__r.Example_2__c
Test__r.OwnerId
Test__r.Owner.Name
Test__r.Owner.Custom__c
Test__r.Owner.Custom__r.Id

$Action.Account.New
$ObjectType.Account
$Api.Session_ID
$Label.firstrun_helptext
.
...
```

How can we match the Salesforce Fields and skip the Global Variables (beginning with '$') using REGEX in JavaScript?

The REGEX should only match the following:

```
CreatedDate
Account.Example_1__c
Account.LastModifiedDate
Test__r.Example_2__c
Test__r.OwnerId
Test__r.Owner.Name
Test__r.Owner.Custom__c
Test__r.Owner.Custom__r.Id
```

`/[\w.]+/g` matches the Salesforce Fields, but it also includes the single dots and the Global Variables in the results.

It should not include `.`, `..`, `...`, etc., or the Global Variables in the matches.

**Additional Examples:**

**1)** Note that this can be a single or multi-line string, and the fields can appear before and/or after other data on the same line:

For example:

```
Test__r.Example_1__c >>>> (Test__r.Example_2__c) <<<< $Action.Account.New >>>> ... Test__r.Example_3__c
```

... should match:

```
Test__r.Example_1__c
Test__r.Example_2__c
Test__r.Example_3__c
```

**2)** These fields are used in formulas (like Excel formulas), so the following:

```
Example_1__c/Example_2__c*Example_3__c-Example_4__c+Example_5__c<>Example_6__c!=Example_7__c,Example_8__c
```

... should return:

```
Example_1__c
Example_2__c
Example_3__c
Example_4__c
Example_5__c
Example_6__c
Example_7__c
Example_8__c
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
(?<!$)(?<=^|\n|\s|\()\w+[\w\.]*
```

We ensure that the section does not start with `"$"`, then mark the start as either the beginning of the string, anything that comes after newline or space, or after an opening parentheses as a special case. It then matches any word that does not start with a `"."`, then allows dots.

[Try it.](https://regex101.com/r/QDqMfo/1)

Comment: It is close, but the fields can have other characters before and afterwards (like in an Excel formula). So, for example, `Example_1__c/Example_2__c*Example_3__c-Example_4__c+Example_5__c<>Example_6__c!=Example_7__c,Example_8__c` should return the eight fields separately (sort of like how `\b` works). So, the boundaries need improvement.

Comment: @SullyCooper then you'll need a list of all the allowed characters and plug it into the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Match the `$` + word/dot chars to skip these matches, and match and capture the rest with word/dot pattern:

```
/\$[\w.]+|(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TVYVri/1). *Details*:

- `\$[\w.]+` - `$` and then one or more word/dot chars
- `|` - or
- `(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)` - Group 1: one or more word chars, and then zero or more sequences of a dot and then one or more word chars.

See the JS demo:

```js
const text = 'Test__r.Example_1__c >>>> (Test__r.Example_2__c) <<<< $Action.Account.New >>>> ... Test__r.Example_3__c';
const rx = /\$[\w.]+|(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)/g;
const matches = Array.from([...text.matchAll(rx)], (x) => x[1]).filter(Boolean);
console.log(matches);
```

The `.filter(Boolean)` removes `undefined` values from the result that appear because of the current pattern logic where we exclude matches without
a capture.